# ptpd 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, timestamps

I am stuck in a messy situation where I should install an environment with the "ptpd" time-service. Now my problem is that my ptpd-server is running on Ubuntu 16.04 which serves the newest ptpd-version 3.2.1 by default. But all my clients are running on Ubuntu 14.04 which serves ptpd-version 2.2.2 by default.
Is there a way I can get version 3.2.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04 or -if not- is there a way I can get version 2.2.2 running on Ubuntu 16.04?
I just have to install the same ptpd-version on both systems.
I do have some experience in Linux but I am not an expert on this so it would be very nice if someone could give me a step-by-step tutorial how to do this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to install ptpd 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with autostart after system reboot, here's my step-by-step tutorial:

1. Download **ptpd2.3.1** from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ptpd/files/ptpd/)
2. Copy **ptpd-2.3.1.tar.gz** to **/opt**:
   `sudo cp ptpd-2.3.1.tar.gz /opt`
3. Navigate to **/opt**
   `cd /opt`
4. Untar the file:
   `sudo tar xvzf ptpd-2.3.1.tar.gz`
5. Delete the file **ptpd-2.3.1.tar.gz**:
   `sudo rm -rf ptpd-2.3.1.tar.gz`
6. Rename the folder **ptpd-2.3.1** to **ptpd**:
   `sudo mv /opt/ptpd-2.3.1 /opt/ptpd`
7. Navigate to **/opt/ptpd**:
   `cd /opt/ptpd`
8. Run the following three commands:
   (If you are configuring the ptpd-**master**, insert:)
   `sudo ./configure`
   (If you are configuring the ptpd-**slave**, insert:)
   `sudo ./configure --enable-slave-only`
   `sudo make`
   `sudo make install`
9. Create a file **ptpdStart.sh** inside the folder **/usr/local/bin/**:
   `sudo touch /usr/local/bin/ptpdStart.sh`
10. Edit that file:
    `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/ptpdStart.sh`
11. Paste the following two lines, then save the file and exit the editor (of course you have to replace **< networkinterface >** with the real name of your networkinterface you want to use for ptpd-traffic.):
    `sleep 30`
     (*sleep* is important(!) as **ptpd** will NOT START if it does not find any functional network-connection on startup)
    If you are configuring the ptpd-**master** insert:
    `sudo /opt/ptpd/src/ptpd2 -M -i <networkinterface>`
    If you are configuring the ptpd-**slave** insert:
    `sudo /opt/ptpd/src/ptpd2 -s -i <networkinterface>`
12. Make the file executable:
    `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ptpdStart.sh`
13. Edit the file **/etc/rc.local**:
    `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
14. *Before* **exit 0** paste the following line then save the file and exit the editor (do NOT delete the **exit 0**):
    `/usr/local/bin/ptpdStart.sh`
15. Reboot your computer and check if ptpd is running:
    `ps -A | grep ptpd2`
    Note: If nothing is shown, then ptpd is not running! In this case check the steps again carefully!

Note! Optional: If you have some more processes you want to autostart via **rc-.local**-file you have to separate those commands by inserting an «&». Example:
`/usr/local/bin/ptpdStart.sh` `&`
`/usr/local/bin/myOtherStartScript.sh`
`exit 0`

For additional options please check the online-documentation of ptpd.

Answer (score 0):

since ptpd [depends on libc6 (>= 2.15)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ptpd) and nothing much else you could try to download the ptpd package from that page and install it on the 16.04 system with `dpkg -i` (or the other way around - install the newer ptpd on the old systems).

Or update your 14.04 systems to 16.04?